# Making various mixed effects models

Tags: r, modeling, mixed-model, effects

I've tried to create three models (using R): an intercept only linear regression, a simple mixed effects regression and a by-subject effects mixed effects regression.

An intercept only regression models the grand mean of a response variable plus error. In `mtcars`, the variable `drat` may be considered a response variable. In the model below, have I correctly modelled the grand mean of `drat`, plus error?

```
interceptOnly <- lm(drat ~ 1, data=mtcars)
```

A simple mixed effects regression models the grand mean of a response variable, plus subject deviation, plus error. In `mtcars`, `drat` may be considered a response variable and `cyl` a subject deviation. In the model below, have I correctly modelled the grand mean of `drat`, plus the deviation of `cyl` from `drat`, plus error?

```
library(lme4)
simpleMixedEffects <- lmer(drat ~ (1|cyl), data=mtcars)
```

A by-subject effects mixed effects regression models the grand mean of a response variable, plus subject deviation, plus condition effect, plus error. In `mtcars`, `drat` may be considered a response variable, `cyl` a subject deviation and `wt` a condition effect. In the model below, have I correctly modelled the grand mean of `drat`, plus the deviation of `cyl` from `drat`, plus the effect of `wt`, plus error?

```
bySubjectMixedEffects <- lmer(drat ~ (1|cyl) + wt, data=mtcars)
```

I have one further question:

How can I model a by-subject varying condition effect model. This is a mixed effects model which models the grand mean of a response variable, plus group deviation from grand mean (random effect), plus condition effect (fixed effect), plus group deviation from condition effect (random effect), plus error. Could someone provide R code that outputs a "by-subject varying condition effect model"?

Comment: More edits made. How can I further improve question?

Comment: As you press me, my personal view is that a good acceptable question will just cite the video as a reference and be focused on questions that other people might ask or difficulties others might express. This looks too much like "Here are some examples I have tried; are they correct?" There are many questions on mixed effects on this site; I can't see this being one of the most useful. Also, you are presupposing some acquaintance with a particular dataset, `mtcars`.

Comment: Question further edited to remove any necessity of familiarity with `mtcars` dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example models seem to be correct.

Your final question concerns varying condition effects. You can include a vayring slope of `mt` in the model with the following command:

```
lmer(drat ~ wt + (1 + wt|cyl), data=mtcars)
```

This model estimates an intercept and a slope for `wt`. These are the fixed effects. Additionally, the model estimates the deviations from these fixed effect for the levels of `cyl`. These are the random effects of the model. Furthermore, a parameter for the correlation between the two random effects is also estimated by the model. If you want to exclude this correlation parameter, you have to change the command to:

```
lmer(drat ~ wt + (1|cyl) + (0 + wt|cyl), data=mtcars)
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to this party but I wanted to point out that *mtcars* is not a suitable dataset for formulating and fitting linear mixed effects models.